# Formatting csv file with python

Tags: python

I have a csv file with the following structure:

```
"txNomeParlamentar";"ideCadastro";"nuCarteiraParlamentar";"nuLegislatura";"sgUF"
"AVANTE;1;1;2015;PP"
```

I need him to stay like this:

```
"txNomeParlamentar";"ideCadastro";"nuCarteiraParlamentar";"nuLegislatura";"sgUF"
"AVANTE";"1";"1";"2015";"PP"
```

I received this .csv file from someone else, so I do not know how the conversion was done. I am trying unsuccessfully with the code below:

```
input_fd = open("/home/gustavo/Downloads/Redes/Despesas/csvfile.csv", 'r')
output_fd = open('dados_2018_1.csv', 'w')
for line in input_fd.readlines():
    line.replace("\"","")
    output_fd.write(line)
    input_fd.close()
output_fd.close()
```

Is it possible to make this change or will I have to do the conversion from an xml file to a csv, and make this change during the conversion?

Comment: seems your file delimiter is a semicolon, and you're trying to parse semicolons **within** string literals as delimiter also, is that correct?

Comment: Yes my delimiter is a semicolon; I need the element between the semicolons to be in quotation marks, as in the second code sample I posted in question

Comment: Will it be either some strings with semicolon between them, and one strings with semicolon within it, or are there any other  kinds of strings present in your csv @Costa.Gustavo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: tell the `reader` to use `delimiter=";"` and `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE`. This will properly split your second line which is a string literal containing your delimiter, which you desire to be split. We'll tweak that data to remove the quotation marks (otherwise our output will be quoted strings like `'"txNomeParlamentar"'`, etc).

```
import csv
with open('file.txt') as f:
     reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=";", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
     data = [list(map(lambda s: s.replace('"', ''), row)) for row in reader]
```

Then: we write the file back out, with the `delimiter=";"`, and `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL` to ensure each item is set in quotes

```
with open('out.txt', 'w', newline='') as o:
     writer = csv.writer(o, delimiter=";", quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
     writer.writerows(data)
```

Input:

```
"txNomeParlamentar";"ideCadastro";"nuCarteiraParlamentar";"nuLegislatura";"sgUF"
"AVANTE;1;1;2015;PP"
```

[image]

Output:

```
"txNomeParlamentar";"ideCadastro";"nuCarteiraParlamentar";"nuLegislatura";"sgUF"
"AVANTE";"1";"1";"2015";"PP"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A couple things.  First, you do NOT have a csv file because in a csv file, the delimiter is a comma by definition.  I'm assuming you want the values in your data file to (1) remain separated by semicolons [why not fix it and make it commas?] and (2) you want each value to be in quotation marks.

If so, I think this will work:

```
# data reader

in_file = 'data.txt'
out_file = 'fixed.txt'
output = open(out_file, 'w')
with open(in_file, 'r') as source:
    for line in source:
        # split by semicolon
        data = line.strip().split(';')             
        # remove all quotes found
        data = [t.replace('"','') for t in data]   
        for item in data[:-1]:
            output.write(''.join(['"', item, '"',';']))
        # write the last item separately, without the trailing ';'
        output.write(''.join(['"', item, '"']))
        output.write('\n')
output.close()
```

If your target user is python, you should consider replacing the semicolons with commas (correct csv format) and forgoing the quotes.  Everything python reads from csv is taken in as string anyhow.

Comment: it's categorically untrue that the delimiter must be a comma, while I guess this is strictly true in the narrowest sense of the term, "csv" is often used a shorthand for any sort of regularly-delimited file: tab-delimited, pipe-delimited, etc. and the `csv.reader` supports the `delimiter` argument so that you can override the default (comma).

Comment: @DavidZemens.  Well, we are going to disagree.  The beauty of .csv is the simplicity and the portability/universality.  Just because somebody made a parser that can use any delimiter, doesn't mean it should be exercised.

Answer (score 1):

Using `csv` module.

**Ex:**

```
import csv

with open(filename) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=";")
    headers = next(reader)    #Read Headers
    data = [row.strip('"').split(";") for row in csvfile]    #Format data

with open(filename, "w") as csvfile_out:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile_out, delimiter=";")
    writer.writerow(headers)   #Write Headers
    writer.writerows(data)     #Write data
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) module to do it if you massage the input data a little first.

```
import csv


#input_csv = '/home/gustavo/Downloads/Redes/Despesas/csvfile.csv'
input_csv = 'gustavo_input.csv'
output_csv = 'dados_2018_1.csv'

with open(input_csv, 'r', newline='') as input_fd, \
     open(output_csv, 'w', newline='') as output_fd:

    reader = csv.DictReader(input_fd, delimiter=';')
    writer = csv.DictWriter(output_fd, delimiter=';',
                            fieldnames=reader.fieldnames,
                            quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    first_field = reader.fieldnames[0]
    for row in reader:
        fields = row[first_field].split(';')
        newrow = dict(zip(reader.fieldnames, fields))
        writer.writerow(newrow)

print('done')
```